# Как и с помощью чего создавать такие эффекты?

Tags: веб-программирование

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне думалось, что это всё делается с помощью canvas, до которого никак руки не доходили. Почитал [руководство](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Tutorial), посмотрел примеры которые они предложили и вообще ни на шаг не приблизился к пониманию того, как это делается...
Может кто-нибудь набросать примерный список того, что нужно знать, что бы реализовывать подобное?

Comment: смекалка + gsap

Comment: @meine мне не интересно как это делать с помощью библиотек ((

Comment: а, ну тогда придётся очень сильно постараться и подучить математику) объяснить как это делается "просто" можно, но займёт очень много времени

Comment: @meine мне бы какой-нибудь маленький путеводитель. Если математику, то какую? Может какие-нибудь специализированные книги для подобного есть?

Comment: если честно, подсказать с книгами не могу, лично я читаю то, что понравилось, как минимум, рекомендую почитать базу по геометрии, а дальше уже углубляться в выш. мат

Comment: как-то я пропустил этот вопрос) все это шейдеры и noise, каждый эффект надо сидеть и разбирать, но в целом подход примерно один - искажение текстурных координат по тому или иному закону + шум на входе

Comment: @StrangerintheQ я уже разобрался во всём этом. Осталось только выучить )

Comment: @h и написать самоответ =)